# What should I expect with position: sticky; bottom: 30px;?

Tags: css, css-position

What should I expect? I expect the `aside` to grab the bottom of the viewport by 30px as you scroll down.

You need to run this in Firefox as it's the only browser that supports [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3rem;
}
p {
  padding: 30px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
img:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section {
  background: #00ff7f;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-height: 1000px;
  margin: auto auto 30px;
}
section:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
article {
  background: #1e90ff;
  padding: 30px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% * 2 / 3 - 30px);
  margin-right: 30px;
}
aside {
  background: #ff6347;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% * 1 / 3);
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, quas? Maxime dolore explicabo nostrum quidem suscipit eveniet libero quam voluptatibus, recusandae exercitationem assumenda voluptates nulla vel temporibus, fuga possimus dolores officiis veritatis quae maiores nisi impedit itaque? Quos optio libero, non nostrum iste, quo natus ex, eos sint itaque omnis? Illum eos, ducimus accusamus totam quasi consequuntur consectetur excepturi temporibus blanditiis aut laborum esse dolorum modi, explicabo illo eligendi cum architecto veniam?  
    </article>
    <aside>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/404/404">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/404/404">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/404/404">
    </aside>
</section>
<section>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sunt, unde fuga, ex tempora nam molestiae autem maiores ducimus, debitis, impedit mollitia laboriosam! Nulla esse voluptatibus laudantium ipsa illo adipisci pariatur, nostrum perferendis quo saepe magnam, veritatis commodi doloribus inventore aspernatur cupiditate assumenda. Cupiditate porro dolorum quo magni ipsum adipisci sit repellendus dolore voluptatibus, omnis enim unde velit quidem expedita iusto modi maxime placeat reprehenderit dignissimos fuga ad atque soluta. Soluta velit natus qui ad hic suscipit dolorum vitae minus quisquam necessitatibus asperiores illum sed dolorem debitis, laborum, praesentium quos dicta molestiae. Iusto animi perferendis dignissimos ut necessitatibus nostrum earum pariatur velit reiciendis quibusdam veritatis neque saepe, mollitia, unde ab ipsam. 
    </p>
</section>
```

http://codepen.io/corysimmons/pen/adjabm?editors=1100

Comment: If you don't want to add code to link to a CodePen, then don't link to CodePen. Better a question with just code, than a question with just a link. If you don't want to include code in your question, period, you can either describe your code in plain English, or present your question in some other way that doesn't require code. If you want to provide feedback about Stack Snippets, you can do so on meta.

Comment: Stack Snippets is not a code editor, it is a code preview tool. Your filler markup is awful (who honestly needs so much filler nonsense for a display: sticky demo?), by the way. And as for what you should expect, this is what you should expect: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/Overview.html#sticky-pos Also, Safari supports `position: sticky`, too.

Comment: Gosh thanks for keeping me honest guys.

Comment: @TylerH: That large amount of filler is there for a reason - to make the article taller than the aside for the purposes of the demo. That said, giving the section an arbitrarily large height works equally well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect the `aside` to grab the bottom of the viewport by 30px as you scroll down.

You're close. Sticky positioning means that the `aside` will hug the bottom of the viewport, but *only* when it would otherwise exceed the bounds of the viewport. Otherwise, it will behave like a regular, relatively positioned box. This is what distinguishes `position: sticky` from `position: fixed` — the latter means the box *always* hugs the bottom of the viewport, regardless of its surrounding layout and of the scroll position.

Because both your `article` and `aside` are floating, the `aside` element doesn't ever get pushed past the bottom of the viewport, and so it doesn't get a chance to stick to the viewport.

Removing the `float` declaration from the `article` element — thereby keeping it in the flow — allows it to push the `aside` beyond the viewport. Note that if the `aside` is taller than the viewport (depending on how you view the snippet), a bottom sticky position will scroll as far as it needs to get 30px (the value of `bottom`) away from the viewport before it begins to stick, after which it will scroll away once the bottom of its containing block (the `section`) exceeds 30px distance from the viewport.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3rem;
}
p {
  padding: 30px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
img:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section {
  background: #00ff7f;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto auto 30px;
}
section:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
article {
  background: #1e90ff;
  padding: 30px;
  width: calc(100% * 2 / 3 - 30px);
  margin-right: 30px;
}
aside {
  background: #ff6347;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% * 1 / 3);
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, quas? Maxime dolore explicabo nostrum quidem suscipit eveniet libero quam voluptatibus, recusandae exercitationem assumenda voluptates nulla vel temporibus, fuga possimus dolores officiis veritatis quae maiores nisi impedit itaque? Quos optio libero, non nostrum iste, quo natus ex, eos sint itaque omnis? Illum eos, ducimus accusamus totam quasi consequuntur consectetur excepturi temporibus blanditiis aut laborum esse dolorum modi, explicabo illo eligendi cum architecto veniam?  
    </article>
    <aside>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/404/404">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/404/404">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/404/404">
    </aside>
</section>
<section>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur sunt, unde fuga, ex tempora nam molestiae autem maiores ducimus, debitis, impedit mollitia laboriosam! Nulla esse voluptatibus laudantium ipsa illo adipisci pariatur, nostrum perferendis quo saepe magnam, veritatis commodi doloribus inventore aspernatur cupiditate assumenda. Cupiditate porro dolorum quo magni ipsum adipisci sit repellendus dolore voluptatibus, omnis enim unde velit quidem expedita iusto modi maxime placeat reprehenderit dignissimos fuga ad atque soluta. Soluta velit natus qui ad hic suscipit dolorum vitae minus quisquam necessitatibus asperiores illum sed dolorem debitis, laborum, praesentium quos dicta molestiae. Iusto animi perferendis dignissimos ut necessitatibus nostrum earum pariatur velit reiciendis quibusdam veritatis neque saepe, mollitia, unde ab ipsam. 
    </p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I think I'm too tired right now to thoroughly grok it, but I kinda see what you're saying.

Kinda sucks that if you're using floats it doesn't really work.

You see what I'm trying to right? Do you have a solution that would work? I ended up making a JS plugin to accomplish the task but it kinda bums me out that I can't use `position: sticky` for that...